# Find the smallest value such that everybody has unique ID

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An organisation has 35000 members and wants to create user IDs consisting of one letter from the English alphabet followed by k digits. What is the smallest value of k such that every member has a unique ID?

What I guessed is by taking 26*10^4. Is this the correct way to show it?

Comment: a "guess" is rarely a good answer. Indeed you can just calculate the number of possibilities as a function of $k$, and then find the smallest integer value for $k$ so that the answer is at least $3~500$.

Comment: @MattiP. I know there are 26 letters and 10 digits ( including 0). I also know that I only need one letter, so by taking 26*10^x and just by guessing x as long it is above 35000, then I am good. Are there any other methods?

Comment: That's exactly how I would answer this question.